# Do incident response plans include playbooks?

Tags: incident-response

Do incident response plans include the playbooks or are the playbooks separate from the incident response plan?

Answer (score 1):

The primary industry standard for playbooks is the Integrated Adaptive Cyber Defense (IACD) Research group, out of Maryland ([John Hopkins](https://www.jhuapl.edu)).

These can constitute any type of cybersecurity response, at the event, alert, notable, or incident level -- for indications and indicators. Playbooks could be part of a CIRT (and therefore IR/DFIR planning), but they could also be part of other structures, such as Cyber Threat Intelligence, Threat Hunting, Security Operations, Security Engineering, Red Teaming, Cybersecurity Analytics, Cyber-Risk Management, and potentially many other specialty areas.

[Playbooks](https://www.iacdautomate.org/intro-to-playbooks-and-workflows) are *conditions, indicators, and controls that drive the need for cybersecurity responses [as] captured [via] orchestration services [for monitoring and execution].*

Playbooks are *process-oriented* and:

- Reflect an org's policies and procedures
- List activities that may require human interaction
- Made sharable from organization to organization

> At the highest level of abstraction, playbooks are a set of process
> oriented steps that enable an organization to meet the requirements
> specified in their policies and procedures. They are a set of human
> understandable actions that document an organizational process
> performed in response to a cyber-event or other defined trigger
> condition. Playbooks are meant to be generic enough for broad
> applicability between organizations while detailed enough to meet
> specific situations. Playbooks may invoke other playbooks, operate
> either serially or in parallel, or initiate a workflow depending on
> the situation or conditions facing the system.